# How to find the vertical scroll bar end position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add div at bottom of the page. For that, I want to find the vertical scroll bar position. I want to add div element at scroll bar end..How can I add div in scroll bar end?

The div element is:

```
<div class = "mydiv">
  <div class = "normal">
     <h3>Thank You</h3>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to display the div at bottom of page if not having scroll bar also. The div want to displays all time in the page. If having scroll bar means, the div element position is the scroll bar end. If not having scroll bar means, the div element want to display at bottom of page.

Comment: Are you sure you need to get the scrollbar position? Can you not just `append()` it to the parent container? Or use `position: fixed; bottom: 0`?

Comment: I want to add the div at scroll bar end. For that only, I need the scroll bar position. If have another way for add div at scroll bar end means, let me know.

Comment: You can use $("your selector").append("your content"). It will add to the last of your selector

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
   if($(window).scrollTop() === ($(document).height() - $(window).height())) {
       $(".mydiv").append("<div>This is a new div.</div>");
   }
})
```

Comment: How can I add the div element here?

Comment: $("#outerDiv").append("<div>This is a new div.</div>");

Answer (score 0):

> How to find the vertical scroll bar end position?

```
isReachToBottom(){ 
    if($(window).scrollTop() === ($(document).height() - $(window).height())) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

> How can I add div in scroll bar end?

```
$("yourtag").append("your footer");
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working fine with one of the requirement for the project, Hope this will solve your problem.

i assume **mydiv** scroll bar is reach bottom of the page.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.mydiv').scroll(function() {    
    if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >=$(this)[0].scrollHeight) {       
        // do add your code 
        $(".mydiv").append("<div>Your New div</div>");    
        }
    });
});
```

You can look at one of my working code in sales-force using this functionality 
[PaginationOnScroll](https://bitbucket.org/nitheshk/paginationusingscrolling)

Answer (score 0):

> here is the code to find scrollbar position

```
     window.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
           let scroll = this.scrollY;
           console.log(scroll)

         });
```